# Jackson fails to parse nested object with exception Constructur Argument #6 has no property name annotation

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, lombok

I have an json input like this

```
{"results" : [
  {
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "SFOData.User"
    },
    "userId": "1",
    "lastName": "TestUser",
    "division": "Manufacturing (MANU)",
    "department": "Production FR (123123123)",
    "firstName": "Example",
    "manager": {
      "__metadata": {
          "type": "SFOData.User"
      },
      "userId": "321321321"
    }
  }
]}
```

I want to parse the result objects of these classes

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
private class StagingUser {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long userId;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String lastName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String division;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String firstName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String department;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private StagingManager manager;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
private class StagingManager {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long userId;
}
```

I try to parse it like this

```
final ObjectNode node = mapper.readValue(result.getBody(), ObjectNode.class);

users = mapper.readValue(node.get("results").toString(), mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, StagingUser.class));
```

The error is

```
Argument #6 of constructor [constructor for my.package.Obj$StagingUser, annotations: {
  interface java.beans.ConstructorProperties=@java.beans.ConstructorProperties(
      value=[userId, lastName, division, firstName, department, manager]
  )
}] 
has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-parameter constructor annotated as Creator
```

Comment: your json is not in correct format you need to enclose with { }

Comment: it's just minified for better showcase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the nested class is not static. For non-static nested classes, an extra parameter containing a reference to the instance of the outer class is introduced. The `@ConstructorProperties` does not have a name for this parameter, that is prepended by the compiler to the list of parameters. Actually, all names in `@ConstructorProperties` are off by one.

Did you know that you can also put `@Getter` and `@Setter` on the class?